# Firebase notification crashing my app in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase notification onMessageReceived() crashing my app when in foreground. The notification does not crash my app when in background and the system shows correctly the notification.

This is the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

This is the code onMessageReceived any thoughts?

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.i(TAG, "ON MESSAGE RECEIVED From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom()); <<<<This line works
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) { <<<<this line crashes

}

}
```

I havent found any suggestions to make it work.

This is the crash

```
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzji@7d60297
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1331)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1495)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:648)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:245)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:262)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:336)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:21)
```

Comment: One observation: That line of code doesn't appear in the stack trace as part of the root cause of the crash.

Comment: I tried to show another   Log.i(TAG, "ON MESSAGE RECEIVED From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom()); after that line but does not appear so i guess is this line causing the crash. Also its working when the app is in background...